# How to filter out data based on a condition

Tags: google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

I have a master list of volunteers. I need another list of volunteers that included their information as long as they aren't selected as inactive. If they are under contact now, contact later, new sign-ups, or even no data. If it says inactive I don't want them in my second worksheet. That's all.

Here is the spreadsheet

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1c075Gervxl0fzZISswhyQ2Z8g61TZhS8IGvl1EEK2o0/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `query()` function:

`=query('Master Volunteer List'!A:I,"Select * where G = ''")`

Or you could use the `filter()` function:

`=filter('Master Volunteer List'!A2:I,'Master Volunteer List'!G2:G = "")`

The filter function won't pickup the header row. So you'll need to

1. place the `filter()` function in cell `A2`
2. And populate the header row in `A1:G1` manually

Answer (score 0):

use this query formula:

```
=QUERY('Master Volunteer List'!A:I, "where not G = 'y'", 1)
```

[image: 0]

---

you can even drop that Inactive column like:

```
=QUERY('Master Volunteer List'!A:I, "select A,B,C,D,E,F,H,I where not G = 'y'", 1)
```

[image: 0]